# Hide root category in the prestashop products URL

Tags: .htaccess, prestashop

I have this website:
https://implementos.com.pe/root/seguridad-carga/cadena-amarre-de-carga-38-609-mt-kinedyne

And I want to hide from the URL the /root/ (When I activate Friendly URL) part of the category, How can I do that?

I need this result:

https://implementos.com.pe/seguridad-carga/cadena-amarre-de-carga-38-609-mt-kinedyne

[UPDATE]

I have only this module for SEO URL
[image]

And is configure like that:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're using a module to change URLs. Is that right? What is your version of Prestashop?

Comment: My Prestashop version is 1.6.1.17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "trouble" is your configuration, just change the: Route to products from 
{categories:/}{rewrite}
to 
{category:/}{rewrite}